# Apply string interpolation on unknown string without str.format()

Tags: python

Given a text file "example.txt" with the following content

`{foo}{bar}`

Is there a way to f-string format this content without the use of `str.format()`?

Something along the lines of:

```py
foo = 'foo'
bar = 'bar'
file = open('example.txt', 'r').read()
print(f'{file}')

# expected result: 'foobar' (?)
```

Comment: No.  That's one of the shortcomings of f-strings -- they must be string literals, not from variables.  What you're doing is exactly what `str.format` was designed for.

Comment: This sounds like XY problem to me so, you can have a look at template engine like `jinja2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll add this for completeness, but as the comments say, what you're asking for is generally ripe with danger due to the fact the file can contain about anything, so ***using good sanitization practices and a `replace` or a `str.format` approach or templating library is far better***.

That said, you can achieve what you want using the dreaded `eval` to make an f-string from a regular string

```
foo = 'foo'
bar = 'bar'

with open('example.txt', 'r') as file:
    content = file.read()

# assuming the file content is like "{foo}{bar}"
result = eval(f"f'''{content}'''")

print(result)
```